# Eclipse - how to change the name of the compiled jar when running a debug config

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, wowza

Basic 101 for Eclipse. If I have an existing java project TestA, how do I change the name of the jar file that is complied when running a debug config so it is testV1.jar?

Comment: Question doesn't make sense. Eclipse does not "compile" JARs (unless you invoke *File > Export > JAR file*)

Comment: OK, then how does the TestA.jar end up in my /lib folder for the debug process?

Comment: What kind of project are you talking about? Plain Java project or something else?

Comment: I just tried creating a Java project with a file and running it and there is no lib folder. Can you give exact steps for what you are doing?

Comment: In this case its a wowza media project, when debug is called it builds a jar file and places it into the /libs folder then starts the application. I assumed this was a standard feature of a eclipse build, being able to build and deploy as part of a debug/run process.

Comment: That must be something specific to the Wowza tools. I added `wowza` as a tag on the question; maybe someone familiar with that tool will chime in.

Comment: Did you import an existing Eclipse project?  You can check the setting by right-clicking on the project in Eclipse and going to Properties, then Build.  You can also go into the folder directly and look for a .project file, open it in something like Notepad++ and see what the builders specify.

Comment: it is added as part of the build.xml, so i could manually change it. 
Thx for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

This is way later than the question but a way to change the JAR filename for a wowza media project is to modify the build.xml file in the project. In the xml property named jar.filename.  Worked for me!